# Group glossaries by first letter

Tags: indexing, glossaries

I am using `glossaries` with `xindy`. It groups entries by first letter and puts a vertical space between groups. How can I change the style of output to show the starting letter for each group at the beginning of them?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{A}{name={A}, description={A is A}}
\newglossaryentry{AA}{name={AA}, description={AA is AA}}

\newglossaryentry{B}{name={B}, description={B is B}}

\newglossaryentry{C}{name={C}, description={C is C}}
\newglossaryentry{CC}{name={CC}, description={CC is CC}}


\begin{document}

Here I cite either \gls{A}, \gls{AA}, \gls{B}, \gls{C} or \gls{CC}.
I want three groups in the glossary output, indicated by \textbf{A},
\textbf{B} and \textbf{C} with entries in them according to their initial letter.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the German community [`MrUnix`](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=68869) I posted such thing.

First you can try the style `indexgroup`.

The command `\printglossaries` doesn't allow any optional argument. To work with your example I use instead `\printglossary` width the optional argument `style=indexgroup`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{A}{name={A}, description={A is A}}
\newglossaryentry{AA}{name={AA}, description={AA is AA}}

\newglossaryentry{B}{name={B}, description={B is B}}

\newglossaryentry{C}{name={C}, description={C is C}}
\newglossaryentry{CC}{name={CC}, description={CC is CC}}


\begin{document}

Here I cite either \gls{A}, \gls{AA}, \gls{B}, \gls{C} or \gls{CC}.
I want three groups in the glossary output, indicated by \textbf{A},
\textbf{B} and \textbf{C} with entries in them according to their initial letter.

\printglossary[style=indexgroup]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know it's been a very long time since this has been written, but I have been looking for exactly what you've done here. I tried using the `indexgroup` style but I seem to get a different output everytime I try, I also copied your MWE but it results in the same output. What I get is simply a `default` in front of the glossary, like this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/N3LO8.jpg  Can you maybe tell me what happened? Has something in the package changed?

Comment: @DavidWright: I tried the mwe above and get the same result.

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean the same result as me or the same result that you posted above?

Comment: i tried some other styles and somehow the only ones that do not work are the group styles, which is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DavidWright: Do you get any errors/warnings? You picture doesn't show the glossar

Comment: No I don't get any warnings or errors at all. When I enter `pdflatex glossaryStyle` then `xindy -M lang/german/duden-utf8 -I xindy -M glossaryStyle -t glossaryStyle.glg -o glossaryStyle.gls glossaryStyle.glo
`and then again `pdflatex glossaryStyle` in the terminal I get normal ouptut, the pdf is built, it also shows a glossary but just not the headings. Here again the picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybka1.jpg

Comment: @DavidWright: I compile via `makeglossaries`.

Comment: `makeglossaries` does the exact same thing, also the same output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8728/discussion-between-marco-daniel-and-david-wright)